# Error: Invalid YAML front matter (ends with ':')

Tags: r, r-markdown

The loop in the params not work, and i receive this message:

```
Error: Invalid YAML front matter (ends with ':')
```

The YAML is:

```
---
title: "Growth"
date: "16 de julho de 2019"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 5
params:
  data: 
  default

---
```

I see the `default` thing in other post, but he not work too.
The code is below:

```
data <- params$data
company <- c("usim5_test.pkl", "vale_test.pkl", "csn_test.pkl", "GGBR4_test.pkl")

for (i in company) {
 rmarkdown::render(
  input = "C:\\Users\\Rafael\\Documents\\ibov\\gurufocus\\macro\\growth_ibov1.Rmd",
output_file = paste0("Growth_",str_sub(i, 1,5),".html"),
params = list(
  data = i
  )
 )
}
```

I expect render the reports for all the files

Comment: I don't know if `default` is an option for `data`, but if it is I would either put it on the same row as `data` (`data: default`) or make sure it is indented by at least two spaces more than `data` is.

Comment: @aosmith i try all this and not work

Comment: It looks like `data:` is only indented by 1 space, when it should be 2

Comment: @aosmith's suggestion worked for me in a standalone document.  I didn't run your loop, because it's not reproducible.

Comment: @camille i check, `data`have 2 spaces

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late (three years later), but i wanted to do the something and had the same problem.

I don't know if there is now easier ways to do this since I'm not a pro on R, still, it works if you first declare `data = NULL` in the YAML.

Comment: "Three years later" ?

Comment: He meant *2Years 7months*

Comment: This doesn't answers the question. The code has some syntactical issue, not a logical one. Please recheck your answer with that of the question.

Comment: I understand from above that even with good syntax the code still didn't work but maybe you can tell me where it is stated that the problem is syntax ?